# Twitter Login failed

Tags: android, twitter

I have downloaded [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) twitter example. I have replaced the old `twitter4j` with `twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar` and in the `onCreate` method I put `loginToTwitter()` in an `AsyncTask` to avoid getting an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I also created a new app on the twitter dev website and added my `consumer key` and `consumer secret`. When I try to Log in, I get the message "Login failed". I downloaded the example because I wanted to see how to accomplish updating your twitter status. How can I fix this problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
Intent shareIntent = findTwitterClient(); 
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "added an item to iCollect(Android)! " + strMake + " " + strModel);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Twitter app not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


public Intent findTwitterClient() {
    final String[] twitterApps = {
            // package // name - nb installs (thousands)
            "com.twitter.android", // official - 10 000
            "com.twidroid", // twidroid - 5 000
            "com.handmark.tweetcaster", // Tweecaster - 5 000
            "com.thedeck.android" }; // TweetDeck - 5 000 };
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent();
    tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < twitterApps.length; i++) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
            String p = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (p != null && p.startsWith(twitterApps[i])) {
                tweetIntent.setPackage(p);
                return tweetIntent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

The problem with this is if my twitter package list is not up to date, the code may exclude some twitter apps.